# Php, "thread safe" SQL operation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, thread-safety

Lets talk about a rating system: users can rate other users. There is an `user` table: USER_ID, USER_NAME and the `rates`: RATER_ID, RATED_ID, RATE (string)
A user may rate someone once, but can change his mind at any time
I know its a bit odd, it can never happen, but lets see how it goes:

```
check if A ever rated B
if no: INSERT INTO
if yes: UPDATE
```

so, in pseudo-code:

```
$rec = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE RATER_ID = a AND RATED_ID = b
if ($rec == 0)
{
    INSERT INTO rates (a, b, rateText);
}
else
{
    UPDATE rates SET RATE = rateText WHERE RATER_ID = a AND RATER_ID = b
}
```

but here comes a problem. Lets suppose two rates arrives at the same time (I know its odd).

```
- rate request A: count(*) is 0, so lets insert
- rate request B: count(*) is 0, so lets insert - SQL ERROR!
```

How to workaround it?

Comment: Most SQL engines handle concurrency problems with **transactions**. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: @JohnWHSmith, MyISAM has no transactions but handles concurrency just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is commonly known as an "upsert" operation.  That is, `UPDATE` if it's already there, otherwise `INSERT`.

[You can set a `UNIQUE` constraint](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-unique-indexes-mysql-databases/) on your columns of `RATER_ID`, `RATED_ID`.  That way, only one row can exist at a time with that specific combination.

From there, use `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Untested, but something like this:

```
INSERT INTO rates (a, b, rateText) VALUES (:a, :b, :rateText)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rateText=VALUES(rateText);
```

Comment: Ive never seen this before!

Comment: if RATER_ID, RATED_ID is a PRIMARY KEY instead of UNIQue constraint, does this still work?

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is `upsert`: if exists then update, else insert.

mysql supports them: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html